# Standard way of finding date diffs - SQL

Tags: sql

Is there a standard way of finding date diff, which is supported in all DBs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, '2017/08/25', '2011/08/25') AS DateDiff;
```

It works well in Microsoft SQL Server, You can try this in your database. It will display `-6` as result due to six years of difference between these two dates.

**In oracle:**

You can simply subtract two dates and get the difference in days. Example:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('2000-01-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') -  
       TO_DATE('2000-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DateDiff
FROM table_Name
```

Comment: `DATEDIFF` is not supported by all DBs. For example Oracle and Hana.

Comment: You can check my answer I have updated. In oracle you can simply subtract two dates and get difference in days. @Kannan

Comment: I am looking for "a" standard way, that works on all DBs.

Comment: @Kannan You can refer https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#i48042 But according to my knowledge there is no standard way.

Comment: Standard SQL would be `date '2000-01-02' - date '2001-01-01'` - to_date() is non-standard